# How do I install channels in Pycharm?

Tags: python, django-channels

I am trying to install channels with pip in pycharm and I am getting the error:

> command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory.

I keep coming across Visual Studio solutions which do not help me.

I am running on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to install it through PowerShell or Terminal outside of Pycharm, and then manually change your settings files and add your routing/consumer files. I never set up my Pycharm environment when I did mine and only ran it through PowerShell, which seemed to work alright. Let me know!

Comment: I tried through terminal and now I get: --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\ROBERT~2\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-3p9j19a4\twisted\

Comment: Hmmmm... I remember when I first switched over to channels, I spend almost a day troubleshooting error codes before I got everything set up. I should have written down what I did, especially since I just switched computers lol, let me check a few things

Comment: Here is a list of all the plugins my site needed if you want to try installing some of these. I know channels needs several to run, not saying that is the problem though:
django,
html5lib==1.0b10
asgi-redis==1.4.3
asgiref==1.1.2
six==1.11.0
channels==1.1.8
daphne==1.3.0
autobahn==17.9.3
txaio==2.8.2
twisted==17.9.0
zope.interface==4.4.3
constantly==15.1.0
incremental==17.5.0
Automat==0.6.0
attrs==17.2.0
hyperlink==17.3.1
djangorestframework==3.7.7
mysqlclient==1.3.10
Flask==0.12.2
olefile==0.44